# Enum support and custom logic in setters of realm object class

Tags: java, android, enums, realm

I'm implementing custom logic in setters and enums in realm object class like this.-

```
public class SellerProducts extends RealmObject{

    public Boolean isValid=true;
    public String is_valid="";
    public String quantity;
    public int quantity_;
    public String enumvalue;
    public void setIs_valid(String is_valid){
        if (is_valid.equals("0")) {
            this.isValid = false;
        }
        this.is_valid=is_valid;
    }
    public String getIs_valid(){
        return this.is_valid;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity){
        this.quantity=quantity;
        try {
            quantity_ = Integer.parseInt(this.quantity);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!this.isValid) {
            setEnum(ProductType.IN_ACTIVE);
        } else if (this.quantity_ <= 0) {
            setEnum(ProductType.OUT_OF_STOCK);
        } else {
            setEnum(ProductType.ACTIVE);
        }
    }

    public String getQuantity(){
        return this.quantity;
    }
    public enum ProductType {
        ACTIVE, IN_ACTIVE, OUT_OF_STOCK
    };
    public void setEnum(ProductType val) {
        this.enumvalue=val.toString().toUpperCase();
    }
    public ProductType getEnum() {
        return ProductType.valueOf(enumvalue);
    }

}
```

when i am calling `getEnum` from the other fragment class it is returning null exception like this

```
*java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:189)
at com.localwizard.realm_db.SellerProducts$ProductType.valueOf(SellerProducts.java:331)
at com.localwizard.realm_db.SellerProducts.getEnum(SellerProducts.java:348)*
```

I'm new to realm so I don't know where I'm wrong?

Comment: You are calling `getEnum()` before you called `setEnum()`. Sounds like a mistake in your logic somewhere, but if intended you can do `return (enumValue != null) ? ProductType.valueOf(enumValue) : null`

Answer (score 0):

Ashish, i think you are not setting the ProductType enum and trying to get it and you geeting the exception. Here is the code which i have tried and it is working fine -

```
public class OtherFragment {
    public static void main(String[] aa)
    {
        SellerProducts sp = new SellerProducts();
        sp.setQuantity("10"); // setting the quantity
        System.out.println(sp.getEnum()); // ACTIVE is set as Enum
        System.out.println(sp.getQuantity()); // 10
        System.out.println(sp.getEnum() == ProductType.ACTIVE); // true
        sp.setEnum(ProductType.IN_ACTIVE); // Now IN_ACTIVE is set
        System.out.println(sp.getEnum() == ProductType.ACTIVE); // false
    }
}
```

If this is not what you want then please add your peace of code, how you meant to set the quantity and trying to get the enum value.

If it answers your question then please accept the answer.

Comment: i am calling setEnum in realmObject in setQuantity itself.and i am just checking the value of getEnum class in other fragment class like this -`sp.getEnum==ProductType.Active`but it is not setting the enum realmobject class itself.so ,does custom logic support in setters in realm object or not?i think that's where i am doing wrong.

Comment: and also `quantity_` is not assigning in `setQuantity` ,it is giving default value.what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have set the quantity and able to get the enum which is being set in setQuantity() method. Later i changed the enum and able to compare with ProductType as well.